# Extracting a value from Two API calls in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

How will I get the value from the first API call and use it in the second API call?

```
var custAcctNum = QueryString.getValue("customer");
                    ProxyData.getData('/customer/api/customers/' + custAcctNum, (data) => {
                        this.setState({ dataCust: dataCust });
                    });

                    var deviceId =  dataCust.ioTDeviceId;
                    ProxyData.getData('device/api/devices/' + deviceId, (data) => {
                        this.setState({ data: data });
                    });
```

Comment: Put the second one in the callback of the first. Or use `async/await`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below. Calling the second async function in the callback of first function.

```
var custAcctNum = QueryString.getValue("customer");
ProxyData.getData('/customer/api/customers/' + custAcctNum, (data) => {
    this.setState({ dataCust: dataCust });
    var deviceId =  dataCust.ioTDeviceId;
    ProxyData.getData('device/api/devices/' + deviceId, (data) => {
        this.setState({ data: data });
    });
});
```